Values of Characters of the representation of permutation
I am just getting into representation theory and while I feel that I understand the general concept of characters, I still struggle with actually calculating them. I have the following problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $F$ be a field. $G$ operates on a set $X$. Then we can define a character in the following way: let $\pi: G \rightarrow S_X, g \mapsto (x \mapsto g.x)$ be the natural homomorphism. Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL_n(K), \sigma \mapsto P^{\sigma}$ be the representation induced by the permutation Matrix $P^{\sigma}$. Then we get a new representation $\rho \circ \pi: G \rightarrow GL_n(K)$ with character $\chi=\chi_{\rho \circ \pi}= |\{x \in X| g.x=x\}|\cdot 1_K$.

So far I believe I understand this construction. However, I struggle with actually calculating values for $\chi$. I am supposed to calculate the following values:

$\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)$

and, assuming that $X=G$, meaning $G$ operates on itself by conjugation:

$\chi(g)$ for every $g \in G$.

The only thing I have so far is that I have shown that $\chi$ must remain constant on the conjugacy classes, which will probably help me evaluate the second value in some way. Is there a general approach to calculating the character?

The character $\chi(g)$ is the trace of $\rho(g)$, i.e. the sum of diagonal entries. Look at the permutation matrix associated to $g$. Which diagonal entries are non-zero?

A convenient way to get the sum of character values is to calculate the multiplicity of the trivial representation in $\chi$.

What I got for the first part is $c \cdot |G|$ where c is the amount of orbits. The way I thought about it was that for each $g \in G$ exactly one element of each orbit must stay fixed. For the second part I am less sure but I believe it is the order of the stabilizer by similar arguments.

Could you explain what you mean by calculating the multiplicity of the trivial representation? This sounds like a more general approach which is what I am mainly looking for.
